# On partial ordering of integers

Tags: analysis

In the book by A.N. Kolmogorov and S.V. Fomin: "Real Analysis" (Dover Edition), Example 4 on p. 20 in the Section on Ordered Sets and Ordinal Numbers says that

"The set of all the integers greater than 1 is partially ordered if $a \leq b$ means that "b is divisible by a" i.e. $a|b$."

The text adds that:

"An element $a$ of a partially ordered set is said to be ${maximal}$ if $a \leq b$ implies $b=a$ and ${minimal}$ if $b \leq a$ implies $b=a$. Thus in Example 4 every prime number (greater than 1) is a minimal element."

I would like to verify if my interpretation of this Example 4 is correct:

Since for example, 2 divides 4, 3 divides 6, 4 divides 8, 5 divides 10, ... we have $ 2 \leq 4, 3 \leq 6, \ldots $. This could be expanded as $\pm 2$ divides $\pm 4$, $\pm 3$ divides $\pm 6$, $\pm 4$ divides $\pm 8$, $\pm 5$ divides $\pm 10$, ... we have $ \pm 2 \leq \pm 4, \pm 3 \leq \pm 6, \ldots $.  We conclude the integers are partially ordered. Is this a correct (perhaps too detailed) interpretation?

Definitions of ${maximal}$ and ${minimal}$ elements of a partially ordered set: Taking the integers as a partially ordered set, the text says that "every prime number (greater than 1) is a minimal element." So, the prime numbers are elements of a partially ordered set the integers. Let $a = 3$ (could be any other prime number) so $a = 3 \leq b= 3$ means that $a= 3$ divides $b=3$ according to the meaning of $a \leq b$ in Example 4 and it does $3/3 = 1$ but we also have that $b=3 \leq a=3$ so $b=3$ divides $a =3$ so we have $b=a=3$. Therefore $a= 3$ is a minimal element of the integers with respect to the meaning of the relation $\leq$ in that Example 4.

Now, can we define a *maximal* element $a$ in the integers that is if $a \leq b$ then $b=a$? I believe not but I may be mistaken or do not interpret the definition of *maximal* element properly. Any comment on that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$3$ being minimal means for all $x$ greater than $1$  if $x$ divides $3$ then $x=3.$ Your version doesn't mention the "for all $x$" part at all so looks wrong (to me).

Comment: Yes, I agree, I have to include "for all $x$". Thank you for commenting.

Comment: If you see the need for quantifier it should be used in your explanation. As it stand now you have only said something where you assume a and b are equal (which doesn't allow reference to *all* x.

Comment: I agree my post needs to be edited with that and also with the content of the answer below. I am starting to learn that topic which is quite new to me.

Comment: @ReneGirard No problem. The point of view of that example takes some getting used to...  In particular it's important that the set on which the divisibility partial order is defined consists of the integers strictly *greater* than $1$ [If $1$ were included a prime wouldn't be minimal by that definition.]

Answer (score 1):

To show that the integers greater than 1 are partially ordered (with the order relation you specified), you need to check the *definition* of a partial order. The formal definition can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition). Note that there are three axioms that need to be verified. In your analysis, you just showed how some of the integers are ordered, but did not *prove* that $\le$ is a partial order.

To show that every prime number (greater than 1) is a minimal element, note that if $a$ is prime and $b\le a$ (which is to say that $a$ is divisible by $b$), then $b$ must equal $a$. This is because the only two divisors of a prime number $a$ are $1$ and $a$. Note that $b\ne 1$ since the set for which the order is defined does not contain $1$. Thus, by the definition you gave, $a$ is a minimal element.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. The reference you gave is very useful as it gives a clear illustration of a partially ordered set for non-negative integers which be extended to all the integers. Looking at my text above, it is clear that I did not understand and see what partially ordered means.

Comment: @ReneGirard No problem. Also, if you found my answer, or the answers/comments of anyone else useful, I suggest giving an upvote to the answer. You can also give the answer that best answers your question a green check mark.

Comment: I will come back to this post later on, incorporate the comments received to follow your recommendation to update the text such that it will be useful to others. Looking at the Wikipedia article on "Partially ordered set" I can see it is not an easy subject but it really fundamental in nature.